# how to check if it's an old tab that was loaded before installing the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Content scripts are loaded on the tabs opened after installing the extension, or the user needs to reload old tabs to make them work.
How can I programmatically check whether the currently opened tab is an old one when the user clicks on the extension popup so that I can inform them about reloading the page once?